# changing the images based on a value from database from 1 to 5

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to display the stars from 1 to 5 on my page basing on the value stored in database. I am trying to write PHP code that echo's the data from the mySQL database in HTML  tag. I don't know if my code is **right** or **wrong**. I am running it throug a while loop and calling the data in many HTML  tags. I have stored the images in my computer in folder images as 1stars.png, 2stars.png, 3stars.png, 4stars.png and 5stars.png. The following is my code.

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from printers where printers_id='1';");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
?>
        <table width="281" border="0" style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:10px;" cellspacing="20">
        <tr>
            <td class="table_text_left"><figure>Value for money:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=images/"<?php echo $row['Value_For_Money'];?>".stars.png alt="5 stars" /></figure></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: write ur code properly

Comment: So what wrong with it, did you received some error message?

Comment: I am receiving a broken image. I  just want to know is there anything wrong in the syntax?

Comment: check it through firebug

Comment: You have to tell us how u are saving this record in the database. A quick idea for you. just echo $row['Value_For_Money']; outside your img tag and see what records are you getting from database. then tell me.

Comment: I have found the answer and added below. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited Coramba's answer and it works fine for me now. Thank you coramba.

from

```
img src="images/<?php echo $row['Value_For_Money']; ?>.stars.png" alt="5 stars" />
```

to

```
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['Value_For_Money']; ?>stars.png" alt="5 stars" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all about quotes. Change

```
<img src=images/"<?php echo $row['Value_For_Money']; ?>".stars.png alt="5 stars" />
```

to

```
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['Value_For_Money']; ?>.stars.png" alt="5 stars" />
```

Comment: @user2148257, Have you seen my second edit? First quote was also in the wrong place. I've noticed that only after posting an answer. Check it now, and if it still won't get ok post your 'html source' here.

Comment: Hi Coramba, I have already got the answer. I have edited your answer. Just removed the concatination symbol before stars.png and it works fine for me. I have posted correct answer below. Thanks for showing me the way to the correct answer. Thanks a lot.